# ASyncDisplayKit (Texture) - Resizing a visible node

Tags: ios, swift, textures, asyncdisplaykit

I have an ASStackLayoutSpec as the container for numerous other nodes.  One of those subnodes is an ASTextNode with a maximumNumberOfLines set to 4.  If a user clicks a "Read More" button underneath, I want to be able to remove the max lines and resize the ASTextNode so that everything displays.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try changing the number of lines to 0 and then call `setNeedsLayout()` and `layoutIfNeeded()` on the node.

It could look like this:

```
func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    textNode.numberOfLines = 0
    textNode.setNeedsLayout()
    textNode.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

The `setNeedsLayout()` may not even be needed, you can try without it and see where it goes.

Comment: This did it - and in Texture, the setNeedsLayout() IS necessary.  Thank you so much!